# Spring - Static Pages

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to display  static pages, When I click on get html pages.It is spring mvc example.I have 1 controller and 2 Jsp page. It show page not found and  show the url 
HelloWeb/HelloWeb/staticPage?

WebController.java

```
 @Controller
  public class WebController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String index() {
   return "index";
}
 @RequestMapping(value = "/staticPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect() {

  return "redirect:/pages/final.htm";
}
}
```

web.xml

```
 <display-name>Spring Page Redirection</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/pages/**" location="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

index.jsp

```
<head>
      <title>Spring Landing Page</title>
   </head>
    <body>
   <h2>Spring Landing Pag</h2>
  <p>Click below button to get a simple HTML page</p>
  <form:form method="GET" action="/HelloWeb/staticPage">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
     <input type="submit" value="Get HTML Page"/>
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>  
     </form:form>
     </body>
```

final.html

```
<head>
     <title>Spring Static Page</title>
     </head>
   <body>
    <h2>A simple HTML page</h2>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your final.html is placed correctly as `/pages/final.htm` ?

Also, in your controller, you specified `/staticPage` as the value of RequestMapping. However, in `index.jsp` your action for the form is `/HelloWeb/staticPage`. These two do not match. Are you sure the project path is set as `HelloWeb` ?

Check the project path
[image]

Try to change the action of the form to `/staticPage`

i.e. `<form:form method="GET" action="/staticPage">`